# $\int_{b-s}^bf(x)\,dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing and $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in [a,b]$, then prove
$$\int_{b-s}^bf(x)\,dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx$$
where $s=\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$.

I have tried probability method and the Bonnet formula, but it seems useless, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx-\int_{b-s}^bf(x)dx &= \int_a^{b-s}f(x)g(x)dx-\int_{b-s}^bf(x)(1-g(x))dx\\
&\ge \int_a^{b-s}f(b-s)g(x)dx-\int_{b-s}^bf(b-s)(1-g(x))dx\\
&=f(b-s)\cdot\left(\int_a^bg(x)dx-s\right)\\
&=0
\end{align}

Thus $$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\ge\int_{b-s}^bf(x)dx$$

Comment: As a suggestion: consider using the align environment when writing longer equations.